# Logging in to test site with Watir

Tags: testing, authentication, watir

While using Watir for testing how do I add a step/code to log in to the test site using a test username and password? Also I'm not sure how to get the field names from the small box for the username and password.

Thanks

Comment: Is there an simpler way I can share code? Thanks.

Comment: Simpler than pasting it in the question itself? Well this site is made so code looks good when pasted in question.

Answer (score 6):

It is very straightforward:

```
#Entering username John Doe and password p@ssw0rd
browser.text_field(:name, "username").set("John Doe")
browser.text_field(:name, "password").set("p@ssw0rd")
browser.button(:name, "Submit").click

#waiting for the welcome message on page
Watir::Wait.until(browser.text.include? "You've been successfully logged").
```

To get exact names of fields, view the source code in browser or use Firebug for Firefox, developer's console in Internet explorer, Dragonfly in Opera.

Comment: You can also identify the text_field by things other than "name", such as id, index and so on, see the page on it: http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/HTML+Elements+Supported+by+Watir

Comment: Good example. I typically create "login(usernane, password)" and "logout()" functions.

Comment: I appreciate the pointers. The page we would like to automate login  to is in Sharepoint. I have IE 8 and when I do Tools > Developer Tools, under the Script tag, the code is attached.

Comment: Looks like I can't attach a file.

Comment: No, you can not attach a file, but you can paste relevant code into question.

Answer (score 0):

Given the basic nature of your question, I'd suggest you should work your way through the [Watir Tutorial](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Tutorial%20%22Watir%20Tutorial)  It covers a lot of things including how to interact with text fields and buttons, which are typically the two things you need in order to work a login page.